# Charset in Jsoup

Tags: html, character-encoding, jsoup

I use Jsoup library.

> After the execution of the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document(language);

File input = new File("filePath" + "filename.html");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input, "UTF-8");

String contentType = "<%@ page contentType=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" %>";
doc.appendText(contentType);

writer.write(doc.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

> In the output html file I receive the following line of text:

```
&lt;%@ page contentType=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; %&gt;
```

instead of

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Its not quite clear what you want that code to do actually, maybe you could include the rest of code also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are escape characters for preventing the browser from treating them as html tags. It's not a problem. It will render correctly when you open the page via a browser

Answer (score 0):

Some problems here:

> ```
> Document doc = new Document(language);
> ```

Don't do this. Use `Jsoup.parse(...)` instead.

> ```
> <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
> ```

This is not HTML, and will probably not get parsed correctly.

Now, for your problem. You should use something like

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(myHtmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), "ISO-8859-1", BaseUrl);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697619/problems-using-extended-escape-mode-for-jsoup-output) for the outputSetting which you may need.